# Build npm-package from private git on install

Tags: npm, build, compilation, create-react-app

I got a private bitbucket repo **A** that I install via npm in my project **B**.

`npm install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org....git`

That works with no problems.

But now I would like to run a build in **A** after installing it.

npm in default comes with a lot of scripts for stuff like that https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

I tryed `postinstall`, `prepare`, `prepublish`, `preinstall` in my package.json in **A**:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "build": "...",
    ...
```

On installing my package **A** in **B** I get npm Error: `npm ERR! premature close`

I would like to run the build on install to remove build files from git (**A**).
In this case the build runs webpack + babel compile.

Project **B** is made with create-react-app.
I don't want to eject create-react-app, setup webpack or compile all node_modules packages.

Any experience with this workflow?

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. You mention that `npm install` works, but then you’re getting an error for the same installation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to eject Project B just adding your Project A as a dependency in package.json is enough. And for Project A please use `"preinstall"` it will run before every npm install including when you run npm install on Project B. And in my case I just tested it it working perfectly in my machine. If you encountering issue I think it might be because of the way you building it maybe? So can you show us the build script?

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepare` since according to the NPM docs it will install dependencies and devDependencies before the package is packaged and installed.

Which is helpful if you are compiling using Typescript, or doing transforms.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "build": "...",
    ...
```

**Note:** If your `dist/build` directory is ignored in `.gitignore`. Add an empty `.npmignore` file to your repository; otherwise the `prepare` script won't build the directory.

Ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install